# What are my dimensions?

Tags: code-golf, geometry

**Task:** Given the area of a triangle, find a [Heronian triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_triangle) with that area. Any Heronian triangle with the specified area is allowed.

A Heronian triangle is a triangle with **integer sides and integer area**. By Heron's formula, a triangle with sides lengths `a,b,c` has area

```
sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
```

where `s=(a+b+c)/2` is half the perimeter of the triangle. This can also be written as

```
sqrt((a+b+c)*(-a+b+c)*(a-b+c)*(a+b-c)) / 4
```

If no such triangle exists, output with a consistent falsey value.

**Input:** A single, positive integer representing the area of the triangle.

**Output:** Any three side lengths for such a triangle OR a falsely value.

Examples:

```
Input -> Output
6 -> 3 4 5
24 -> 4 15 13
114 -> 37 20 19
7 -> error
```

[Standard loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default?answertab=votes#tab-top)

This is code golf, shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Can you write a relatively concise definition of a Heronian triangle in your challenge?

Comment: @Okx: Is it not clear that it is a triangle with integer sides and integer area?

Comment: @Okx: That is the idea. All you need to do is find one such example for the given area if it exists.

Comment: From the Wikipedia link: "A Heronian triangle is a triangle that has side lengths and area that are all integers."

Comment: I understand now, but you might want to make it clearer in the question.

Comment: Could you please explain what is confusing about the definition in the question?

Comment: @NeilA. I think what people were looking for were the relevant formulas without needing to follow a link. I editing those in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>17</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 byte thanks to Erik the outgolfer (make use of the quick, `¥`)

```
SHð;_P
ṗ3Ç⁼¥Ðf²Ḣ
```

Brute force application of Heron's formula.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ASEA3v//U0jDsDtfUArhuZczw4figbzCpcOQZsKy4bii////MjQ)** (reaches the 60s time out for the 114 tests case. Takes 3m 30s locally - it does check 114<sup>3</sup> = 1,481,544 triples)

#### How?

A true golf solution - given an area `a` it finds **all** tuples of three integers between `1` and `a` (even with repeated triangles and ones of no area), gets their area and filters for those with the desired area (it doesn't even stop as soon as one is found, it ploughs through them all and pops the first result afterwards). Yields `0` if none exists.

```
SHð;_P - Link 1, get the square of the area of a triangle: list of sides
S      - sum the sides (get the perimeter)
 H     - halve
  ð    - dyadic chain separation (call that p)
    _  - subtraction (vectorises) =    [p-side1,  p-side2,  p-side3]
   ;   - concatenate              = [p, p-side1,  p-side2,  p-side3]
     P - product                  =  p*(p-side1)*(p-side2)*(p-side3)
                                  = the square of Heron's formula = area squared

ṗ3Ç⁼¥Ðf²Ḣ - Main link: number a (area)
ṗ3        - third Cartesian power (all triples of [1,area] : [[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[2,2,2], ... ,[a,a,a]]
       ²  - square a
     Ðf   - filter keep if:
    ¥     -   last two links as a dyad:
  Ç       -     call last link (1) as a monad f(list of sides)
   ⁼      -     left (that result) equals right (square of a)?
        Ḣ - head - get the first one (an empty list yields 0, perfect for the falsey case)
```

Comment: I figured someone would try to brute force this, nice!

Comment: @NeilA. I imagine most golf submissions will be brute force for this challenge - but some may manage to be golfed while being less ridiculously inefficient than this one.

Comment: You can replace `ç` with `Ç⁼¥` and remove the second line entirely.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Oh, thanks, I was wondering how to go about that...

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES7), <s>109</s> <s>102</s> <s>100</s> 98 bytes

Returns either an array of 3 integers or `false`. Like the [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121816/58563), this is brute forcing Heron's formula.

```js
A=>[...Array(A**3)].some((_,a)=>A*A/(r=[b=a/A%A|0,c=a/A/A|0,a%=A],p=a+b+c>>1)/(p-a)/(p-b)==p-c)&&r
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

A=>[...Array(A**3)].some((_,a)=>A*A/(r=[b=a/A%A|0,c=a/A/A|0,a%=A],p=a+b+c>>1)/(p-a)/(p-b)==p-c)&&r

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(6)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(24)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(114)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(7)))
```

---

### Recursive version, 83 bytes

Returns an array of 3 integers or throws a recursion error. Sadly, it only works for small inputs.

```js
f=(A,n)=>A*A/(r=[a=n%A,b=n/A%A|0,c=n/A/A|0],p=a+b+c>>1)/(p-a)/(p-b)==p-c?r:f(A,-~n)
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(A,n)=>A*A/(r=[a=n%A,b=n/A%A|0,c=n/A/A|0],p=a+b+c>>1)/(p-a)/(p-b)==p-c?r:f(A,-~n)

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(6)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(24)))
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 69 bytes

```hs
f a=take 1[t|t<-mapM(\_->[1..a])":-)",a*a==product[sum t/2-x|x<-0:t]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mkGhbkpidqmAYXVJTYqObm1jgqxETr2sXbainlxirqWSlq6mkk6iVaGtbUJSfUppcEl1cmqtQom@kW1FTYaNrYFUSG/s/NzEzT8FWAaRZQaOgKDOvRC9NUyHaTMfIRMfQRMc89j8A)

Outputs a singleton of a list of three triangle sides like `[[3.0,4.0,5.0]]`. Impossible inputs give `[]`. Technically only `False` is Falsey for Haskell, but because Haskell requires all possible outputs to be of the same type, it can't be used. If an error could be used as Falsey, `[...]!!0` would save 3 bytes over `take 1[..]`.

Tries all triples `t` of possible side lengths each ranging from `1` to the area `a`. Heron's formula is used to check if the area matches via `(s-0)(s-x)(s-y)(s-z)==a*a` where `s=(x+y+z)/2` is `sum t/2`. The product `(s-0)(s-x)(s-y)(s-z)` is expressed as a `product` with elements taken from `0:t`, i.e. the triple as well as 0.

Comment: +1 for smiley face, even if it's sorta a noop

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), <s>131</s> <s>123</s> 118 bytes

```python
n=input()
t=n*3;r=i=c=0
while c<t:
 i+=1;a,b,c=i%t,i/t%t,i/t/t;s=a+b+c>>1
 if(s-a)*s*(s-b)*(s-c)==n**2:r=a,b,c
print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2-pypy#JYxLDgIhEAX3nIKNyfAxI@pq8M1doKOxE0Mm0BOPj6ibept61Qu4bLtMRgmKvcQKBuGk3k9@3TXdZFGaHUJMPnsCH8TzLH/OEhuSy47WNQztMbVjMrbZsdl8SQajas9Lxe@vtspFdO09hOsH)

While this also works on CPython, PyPy is a lot faster and is able to compute the triangle for 114 in the time limit on TIO.

Timings from my machine:

```bash
$ echo 114 | time pypy2 d.py
        0.55 real         0.52 user         0.02 sys
$ echo 114 | time python2 d.py
       52.46 real        51.76 user         0.27 sys
```

Answer (score 2):

## F#, <s>170</s> <s>156</s> 152 bytes

```fs
let f(a,b,c)=
 let s=(a+b+c)/2.0
 s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)
let g A=[for a in 1.0..A do for b in a..A do for c in b..A do yield a,b,c]|>List.find(f>>(=)(A*A))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc3LCsMgFATQfb7iEih487A2dKvgvn9QuvARg5BoiW4K@XeLoYtuBuYwMC6NWwyxlHXO4Iga9GCQN1Br4kT1ujd4nShrIHUkjQpr6jMNNnW2gORPF3dQ4APcKKNUgo1QSVdSf2Aq6B98/LxaOD9fh3j4lKnzwRInBOFIZCcRywLTnbJDvHcfsmsvsi1f)

## "Ungolfed"

```fs
let calculateArea (a, b, c) =
    let s = (a+b+c)/2.0
    s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)

let getTriangle A =
    [  for a in 1.0..A do
       for b in a..A do
       for c in b..A do yield a,b,c
    ]
    |> List.find(calculateArea>>(=)(A * A))
```

If there are no results found, the program will fault. If this is not desired, I have to replace `List.find` with either `List.filter` (+2 bytes) which will produce an empty list in case nothing is found or `List.tryFind` (+3 bytes), returning None in case no triangle was found.

I always find that a golfed F# version is still reasonable legible.

Comment: I don't know F#, but I imagine you could dispense with the `System.Math.Sqrt` and compare the resulting value to `A * A`?

Comment: @Sean Of course! Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Replacing `1.0..A [...] 1.0..A [...] 1.0..A` with `1.0..A [...] a..A [..] b..A` should save you a couple bytes and speed you up a little (if it works; I have very minimal F# experience).

Comment: @CAD97 It does! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 59 bytes

```
Solve[Area@SSSTriangle[a,b,c]==#>c>b>a>0,{a,b,c},Integers]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pzg/pyw12rEoNdEhODg4pCgzMS89JzU6USdJJznW1lbZLtkuyS7RzkCnGixUq@OZV5KanlpUHKv2P6AoM69EwUEhDYjNuJB5Rib/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 23 bytes

```
/mu*G-/sd2Hd/sd2^UQ3^Q2
```

Which prints a truthy/falsy value, or

```
fq^Q2u*G-/sT2HT/sT2^UQ3
```

which prints out all possible solutions, and is horribly slow for large inputs.  Put 'h' at the beginning to only print one.

Explanation:

```
fq^Q2u*G-/sT2HT/sT2^UQ3
                    UQ    # List of numbers from 0 to input-1
                   ^  3   # All triples of these numbers
f                         # Filter this by the following test (on variable T, based on Hero's formula)
     u*G-/sT2HT/sT2       # s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c), where s is the sum of the triple over 2 (calclated as /sT2 )
 q^Q2                     # Test if equal to input ^2
```

[Try it](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Fmu%2aG-%2Fsd2Hd%2Fsd2%5EUQ3%5EQ2&input=6&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=6%0A7%0A24&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 54 bytes

```
->\a{first {a*a==[*] .sum/2 «-«(0,|$_)},[X] ^a xx 3}
```

Brute force search of all possibles sides up to one less than `a`, the input area.

- `^a` is the range of numbers from 0 to `a - 1`.
- `[X] ^a xx 3` reduces, by cross product, three copies of that range, producing all triplets from `(0, 0, 0)` to `(a - 1, a - 1, a - 1)`.
- We look for the `first` triplet such that the area of the triangle with those sides equals `a`, using [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula).

Within the code block given to `first`:

- `$_` is the triplet.  Call it `(x, y, z)` here.
- `(0,|$_)` is the same triplet but with `0` prepended: `(0, x, y, z)`.
- `.sum / 2` is half the perimeter (a quantity which is named `s` in the usual expression of Heron's formula).
- `.sum / 2 «-« (0, |$_)` is the subtraction hyperoperator with `s` on the left and the `(0, x, y, z)` on the right, giving `(s - 0, s - x, s - y, s - z)`.
- `[*]` then reduces that quadruplet with multiplication, giving the square of the area.
- `a * a ==` looks for a squared area equal to the square of the given area.

If no triplet is found, `Nil` (which is falsey) is returned.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 77 bytes

with mathematica's **Solve**

```
s=(a+b+c)/2;d=Sqrt[s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)];Solve[d==#&&0<a<b<c<#,{a,b,c},Integers]&
```

---

### Mathematica, 117 bytes

brute force

```
s=(a+b+c)/2;l="error";(For[a=1,a<#,a++,For[b=1,b<a,b++,For[c=1,c<b,c++,If[Sqrt[s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)]==#,l={a,b,c}]]]];l)&
```

Comment: Mathematica doesn't have a builtin? Surprising.

Comment: @ovs you can save one byte on that with `Area@SSSTriangle[a,b,c]` too.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/documentation), 76 bytes

```
f s=[[a,b,c]|a<-[1..s],b<-[1..a],c<-[1..b],a*a*c*c-(a*a+c*c-b*b)^2/4==4*s*s]
```

This outputs a list of lists containing all possible integral sizes that generate the correct area via brute force (outputting the empty list if there are none). The caveat being it outputs them as doubles because of that division in the middle but their fractional part is always 0.

If you for some reason can't take that,

```
f s=[[a,b,c]|a<-[1..s],b<-[1..a],c<-[1..b],4*a*a*c*c-(a*a+c*c-b*b)^2==16*s*s]
```

This will output the answers as a list of integer lists for <s>89</s> 77 bytes total or <s>13</s> 1 extra bytes. (Thanks to Neil)

If you need / want only the first element just putting `!!0` at the end will give you only the first element if there are numbers that apply and an error if there's none for 3 more bytes and `take 1` at the beginning will take the first element without erroring out for 6 more bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#JcYxDsIwDADAva/wwADGKQrKRvMDfhAZyU5TlIGAmg4d@Hso6nDStQmqD0FIKfJXBhNs31cm3SdMcZ8yCQpGjOa45fyPop4e14vz3mHFyl33klzAw/iGFQYDz7Tcc0k3@My5LHCAaTMnGWFtzVr3Aw)

Comment: If you want to avoid doubles can't you just multiply the equation by 4 on each side?

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, <s>70</s> 69 bytes

```
Prompt A
For(B,1,A
For(C,1,B
For(D,1,C
(B+C+D)/2
If A2=Ansprod(Ans-{B,C,D
Then
Disp B,C,D
Return
End
End
End
End
/
```

Displays the three side lengths if there is a triangle, throws a syntax error if there isn't (thanks to the `/` at the end).

-1 byte thanks to [Sean's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121811/what-are-my-dimensions/121836#comment298798_121824) on a different answer

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 22 bytes

```
;╗R3@∙⌠;Σ½;)♀-π*╜²=⌡░F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#ASwA0///O@KVl1IzQOKImeKMoDvOo8K9OynimYAtz4Aq4pWcwrI94oyh4paRRv//Ng)

Explanation:

```
;╗R3@∙⌠;Σ½;)♀-π*╜²=⌡░F  (implicit input: A)
;╗                      store a copy of A in register 0
  R                     range(1, A+1)
   3@∙                  ternary Cartesian product (all triples with values in [1, A])
      ⌠;Σ½;)♀-π*╜²=⌡░   filter: take triples where function returns truthy
       ;Σ½                make a copy of the triple, compute s = (a+b+c)/2
          ;)              make a copy of s, move it to the bottom of the stack
            ♀-            subtract each value in the triple from s
              π*          product of those values and s (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
                ╜²        A*A
                  =       compare equality (does area of triangle with given dimensions equal input?)
                     F  take first triple that satisfies the filter (or empty list if none)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Casio Basic, 123 bytes

```
For 1⇒a To n
For 1⇒b To n
For 1⇒c To n
If(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)|s=(a+b+c)/2)=n^2
Then
Print{a,b,c}
Stop
IfEnd
Next:Next:Next
```

Standard brute force solution. 122 bytes for the code, 1 byte to specify `n` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 119 + 2 `-pa` = 121 bytes

```perl
for$a(1..$_){for$b(1..$_){map{($t=($s=($a+$b+$_)/2)*($s-$a)*($s-$b)*($s-$_))>0&&"@F"==sqrt$t&&($\="$a $b $_")}1..$_}}}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBCgIhFEV/ZZCHaIOm0SyNVu36g2B4QkFQ6ag78dd7WUyLy@GcxY3X9JiIbiEBCqs1zLJ@xf/libEKKE5A7sMR/Njzdic3vSjAlX7lLOXBcM6OJ@ZcXlKBwrmAi2OAA/gBZibb77q1Voms3b9DLPfwyqTOkzbWkIr4AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 90 bytes

```javascript
S=>(g=(a,b,c,r=(a+b+c)/2)=>r*(r-a)*(r-b)*(r-c)^S*S?!c&&g(S,a,b)||--a&&g(a,b,c):[a,b,c])(S)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxNCsIwFIT33sJNedMmSosoCKmHyFIUkmcblNJIKq5695hmKd3MzwczL/M1E4fn@yNH/@hir6JWLTlFRljBIqRQ2Yqxb6DaUFKQBovarIy7LvVly0XhSIu0wTxLaZaaD3C@Zr@BNCL7cfJDtxu8I@rpCGDzx5rDCqzrNXpKLP4A)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 92 bytes

```javascript
S=>(g=(a,b,c,r=(a+b+c)/2)=>(c?r*(r-a)*(r-b)*(r-c)==S*S&&[a,b,c]:g(S,a,b))||--a&&g(a,b,c))(S)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxBCsIwFATQvQcJf9pEaRGFQvQQWYqL5NsGpTSSlq569xjrTroZhgczLzvbkePzPakhPNrU6WT0hbwmK51kGXMpXck41MjO11hQVBbfdGsytDaFEeK2Lu6NJyNzBZZFKSuE/10BZJA4DGPo230fPFFHJwC7P6uPG1hVW3rOlj4)

Usual search

Where's the proof every length <= area?

Answer (score 0):

## Uiua, 54 Bytes

Standard bruteforce solution. Returns all possible results.

```
▽=⊙:≡(√/×⊂-:⊙:.÷2/+.).☇1+1⇡⊂⊂...
```

[Try It](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__4pa9PeKKmTriiaEo4oiaL8OX4oqCLTriipk6LsO3Mi8rLiku4piHMSsx4oeh4oqC4oqCLi4uMTIK)

Explanation:

```
▽=⊙:≡(√/×⊂-:⊙:.÷2/+.).☇1+1⇡⊂⊂...
                       ☇1+1⇡⊂⊂... # generate tuples [1, a]^3
                      . # save a copy to output
    ≡(√/×⊂-:⊙:.÷2/+.) # for each side length tuple calculate the area
                    . # save a copy of the current tuple so we can do s-a,s-b,s-c later
                ÷2/+ # calculate s by summing and dividing by 2
               . # copy s so we can multiply by it later
           :⊙: # bring the saved tuple to the top of the stack
          - # calculate s-a,s-b,s-c
         ⊂ # join s to the array containing [s-a,s-b,s-c]
       /× # reduce multiply to get the product of all of the elements
      √ # final square root to calculate area
  ⊙: # bring area we are looking for up to the second position in the stack
 = # create a boolean mask which selects all areas which matched
▽ # keep the tuples that had the correct area
```