# Triangle area from side lengths

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

Output the area \$A\$ of a triangle given its side lengths \$a, b, c\$ as inputs. This can be computed using [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula):

$$ A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\textrm{, where } s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}.$$

This can be written in various ways, such as

$$ A= \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}$$
$$ A= \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^4+b^4+c^4)}$$

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#Formulation) for more. Related: [What are my dimensions?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121811/20260)

The inputs will be three positive integers that [satisfy the triangle inequality](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/199353/20260) and so are sides of a non-degenerate triangle. While the order of the three sides doesn't affect the output, you may not assume they're given in a particular order like sorted. You may take inputs in a list or tuple or the like. Any reasonable float output is fine.

**Test cases**

```
1 1 1 -> 0.4330
3 4 5 -> 6.0000
9 3 7 -> 8.7856
```

Comment: [There is a similar but closed challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11020/9288).

Comment: [Similar challenge on anagol (round to int)](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?area+of+triangle)

Comment: Can you output an exact real number, if the language natively supports such a type?

Comment: @A.Rex What do you mean, like outputting sqrt(n)?

Comment: @xnor: Can the Mathematica answer be shortened by removing the call to N[..], which returns a numeric approximation of an exact number?

Comment: @A.Rex If it's a fraction, that's fine, but not if it has square roots.

Answer (score 11):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 20 bytes

```
N@*Area@*SSSTriangle
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@9/PQcuxKDXRQSs4ODikKDMxLz0n9X9AUWZeSbSygq6dQpqCg4OCcqyCmoK@g0J1taGOAgjV6ihUG@somOgomIKYljoKQJ55be1/AA)

Built-in.

---

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 22 bytes

```
((#.#)^2-2#.#^3)^.5/4&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@19DQ1lPWTPOSNcISMcZa8bpmeqbqP0PKMrMK4lWVtC1U0hzUI5VUFPQd1CorjbUUQChWh2FamMdBRMdBVMQ01JHAcgzr639DwA)

-2 bytes by porting [loopy walt's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250455/9288).

Takes input as a list. Using the formula \$A= \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^4+b^4+c^4)}\$.

---

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

```
1##&@@(+##/2-{0,##})^.5&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcc7CoAwEEXRrTwYCIrjXxELZZZgLwpBFC1iIelC1h4VbnGu0fbcjbbXpsOBIZRESiRKiPIqdQUT@XjNWhWm57rtTEhHHBABLVDIBc6VjD/PcDWjYbQ/e8Z3nffhBQ)

Based on [chyanog's answer to another challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11032/9288).

Using the formlula \$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\textrm{, where } s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}\$.

Comment: What an expressive name of a builtin.

Comment: As it is named as `SSSTriangle`... Is there something like `SASTriangle`, `ASATriangle`, `AASTriangle`, or even `HLTriangle`?

Comment: @tsh [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxMEvMTe1OFpJK6QoMzEvPSdVKfb/fwA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: @tsh [`AASTriangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AASTriangle.html), [`ASATriangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ASATriangle.html), [`SASTriangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SASTriangle.html), [`SSSTriangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SSSTriangle.html), [`Triangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Triangle.html).

Answer (score 7):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 13 bytes

```
{%*/x-/x%2}0,
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pW1dKv0NWvUDWqNdDh4kpTMARBIG2sYKJgCqQtgSxzAL4FCGI=)

There is! -2 bytes thanks to @ovs.

```
{%*/x-/x%2}0,  x: a length-3 array containing the three sides
           0,  prepend a 0
       x%2     (0; a/2; b/2; c/2)
    x-/        (0 a b c) - a/2 - b/2 - c/2
 %*/           sqrt(product of the above)
```

---

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 16 bytes

```
{%-s*/x-s:+/x%2}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pW1S3W0q/QLbbS1q9QNarl4kpTMARBIG2sYKJgCqQtgSxzAOl9CX4=)

<s>There must be a shorter way..?</s>

```
{%-s*/x-s:+/x%2}  x: a length-3 array containing the three sides
        s:+/x%2   s: half sum of x
      x-          (a-s; b-s; c-s)
  -s*/            -s * (a-s) * (b-s) * (c-s)
 %                sqrt
```

Comment: there is a shorter way: [`{%*/x-+/x%2}0,`](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pW1dKv0NXWr1A1qjXQ4eJKUzAEQSBtrGCiYAqkLYEscwDFzwiN)

Answer (score 7):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/products.htm), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

-1 thanks to @Bubbler.

```
.5*⍨0∘,×.-2÷⍨+/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qpTIxJz89PrEgZ8GCpaUlaboWN80e9U191DZBQ89U61HvCoNHHTN0Dk_X0zU6vB3I1dbXPLRCw1ABCDU1jBVMFEw1NSwVjBXMNSG6oYbADAMA)

```
┌──┼───────┐
.5 *⍨  ┌───┼────┐
      0∘, ×.- ┌─┼──┐
              2 ÷⍨ +/

    0∘,          left  argument: input with 0 prepended     0 a b c
          2÷⍨+/  right argument: sum of input divided by 2  (a+b+c)/2 = s
       ×.-       left minus right, then take the product    (0-s)(a-s)(b-s)(c-s)
.5*⍨             square root
```

`(0-s)(a-s)(b-s)(c-s)` is equivalent to `(s-0)(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)` as there is an even number of items being multiplied.

Comment: You don't need `⍨` after `-` since there are 4 items to be multiplied.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>17</sup> 16 bytes

```
2%:[:*/0&,-+/%2:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/jVStoq209A3UdHS19VWNrP5rcqUmZ@QrpCkYgiCMY6xgomCqAONZAvnmXKkVmSXq6lxgdQq6dgoGeibGxgZcEKVAvpmeARBwgRWD@BZ65hamZv8B)

*-1 thanks to [Bubbler's K approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250450/15469)*

The interesting insight (obvious when spelled out but not always when searching for a golf) is: When taking the product of an even number of elements, it is equivalent to taking the product of their negatives.

### original, 17 bytes

```
2%:[:*/+/-:@-0,+:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/jVStoq209LX1da0cdA10tK3@a3KlJmfkK6QpGIIgjGOsYKJgqgDjWQL55lypFZkl6upcYHUKunYKBnomxsYGXBClQL6ZngEQcIEVg/gWeuYWpmb/AQ)

- `0,+:` Double each input and prepend 0
- `+/...-` Subtract each of those from sum of input
- `-:@` And halve each result
- `[:*/` Product
- `2%:` Root

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 47 bytes

```
lambda a,b,c:(4*a*a*b*b-(a*a+b*b-c*c)**2)**.5/4
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY39XMSc5NSEhUSdZJ0kq00TLQSgTBJK0lXA8jQBjGStZI1tbSMgFjPVN8Eom19QVFmXolGmoaljrGOuaYmRHTBAggNAA)

Classic boring solution. There might be a shorter way to express this formula, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
HSạŻP½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98j@OGuhUd3Bxza@z/aWMdExzT2cPt/AA)

Don't ask me why the chaining works...

```
H      # Half of
 S     # The sum of the input
  ạ    # Absolute difference with
   Ż   # The input, with a 0 prepended
    P½ # Take the square root of the product
```

Comment: https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Tutorial 4.2 "Then the following patterns are matched against, *from top to bottom*:"

Comment: Yeah, I don't see anything strange about the chaining.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0šDO;αPt
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4OhCF3/rcxsDSv7/jzbWMdExjQUA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/g6MLXfytz20MKPmv8z862lAHCGN1oo11THRMgbSljrGOeWwsAA).

**Explanation:**

Uses the default formula:

$$s=\frac{0+a+b+c}{2}$$
$$ A=\sqrt{abs(0-s)\times abs(a-s)\times abs(b-s)\times abs(c-s)}$$

```python
0š        # Prepend a 0 in front of the (implicit) input-triplet
  D       # Duplicate the list
   O      # Sum the copy
    ;     # Halve the sum
     α    # Get the absolute difference between this sum and the values in the list
      P   # Take the product
       t  # Square root
          # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: The signed difference will work just as well as the average difference (it doesn't matter if you have (a-s) instead of (s-a) because over the 4 terms the overall result will be positive.) I'm guessing that won't make it any shorter though?

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I know. I've indeed just used subtracts instead of absolute difference in [my ported MathGolf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250466/52210) for that reason. But changing the `α` to `-` indeed won't make a difference in byte-count.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 32 bytes

```
lambda v:((v@v-2*v*v)*v@v)**.5/4
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3FXISc5NSEhXKrDQ0yhzKdI20yrTKNLWATE0tLT1TfROouqS0ovxchbzS3IJKhczcgvyiEoXEoqLESq6Cosy8Eo00DTBPI9pQBwhjNTU10SWMdUx0TLFJWOoY65iDJCA2LVgAoQE)

#### Previous [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 33 bytes

```
lambda v:(v@v*v@v-2*v**3@v)**.5/4
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3FXMSc5NSEhXKrDTKHMq0gFjXSKtMS8vYoUxTS0vPVN8EqjAprSg_VyGvNLegUiEztyC_qEQhsagosZKroCgzr0QjTQPM04g21AHCWE1NTXQJYx0THVNsEpY6xjrmIAmITQsWQGgA)

#### Previous [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 36 bytes (@alephalpha)

```
lambda v:(v@v*v@v-2*v**2@v**2)**.5/4
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3VXISc5NSEhXKrDTKHMq0gFjXSKtMS8vIAURoamnpmeqbQNUmpRXl5yrkleYWVCpk5hbkF5UoJBYVJVZyFRRl5pVopGmAeRrRhjpAGKupqYkuYaxjomOKTcJSx1jHHCQBsWnBAggNAA)

#### Previous [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 37 bytes

```
lambda v:((v@v)**2-2*v**2@v**2)**.5/4
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3VXMSc5NSEhXKrDQ0yhzKNLW0jHSNtMqAlAOIAPL1TPVNoIqT0orycxXySnMLKhUycwvyi0oUEouKEiu5Cooy80o00jTAPI1oQx0gjNXU1ESXMNYx0THFJmGpY6xjDpKA2LRgAYQGAA)

Expects a numpy vector containing the three side lenghts.

Comment: `(v@v)**2` -> `v@v*v@v`.

Comment: Are you allowed to leave out the `import numpy` statement, per meta rules?

Comment: [Yes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10085/107561) @solid.py

Comment: @solid.py If you could use them without directly referencing them which looks tricky to me.

Comment: @loopywalt Consider `from itertools import*` and any function that you use from it e.g. permutations. Does that count? I mean you are not explicitly referencing `itertools.permutation`.

Comment: @solid.py look, why don't you just read the meta discussion? It is all nicely explained there.

Comment: @loopywalt It's not really explained well. If you feel like you understand it kudos.
In any case this rule taxes every `import` statement except the `import numpy`.

Comment: @solid.py Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. Arguably, any module that defines new types that have useful functionality accessible through methods or overloaded operators would qualify.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>30</s> 28 bytes

```
\(x)prod(sum(x)/2-c(0,x))^.5
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhZ7YjQqNAuK8lM0iktzgUx9I91kDQOdCk3NOD1TiJKbXmkayRqGOgogpKmprKBrp2CgZ2JsbMAFkjDWUTDRUTCFSpjpGQABWMJSRwEoZw6VsNAztzA1g5i4YAGEBgA)

Inspired by [@Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250460/55372).

---

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>32</s> 30 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes by looking at [@loopywalt's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250455/55372).*

```
\(x)((x%*%x)^2-2*x^3%*%x)^.5/4
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhb7YjQqNDU0KlS1VCs044x0jbQq4owhHD1TfROIopteaRrJGoY6CiCkqamsoGunYKBnYmxswAWSMNZRMNFRMIVKmOkZAAFYwlJHAShnDpWw0DO3MDWDmLhgAYQGAA)

Takes input as a vector of sides.

Uses the formula
$$ A= \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^4+b^4+c^4)}$$

with observation that sum of squares of elements from `x` is a dot product of `x` with itself. So with \$x=[a,b,c]\$ and \$y=[a^3,b^3,c^3]\$:

$$ A= \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(x \cdot x)^2-2(y\cdot x)}$$

Comment: Note that the 28-byte answer is also essentially identical to [plannapus's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11022/95126) to the [previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11020/9288) from 9 years ago...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen indeed, thanks for that reference.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>59</s></sup> 51 bytes

```c
#define f(a,b,c)sqrt(4*a*a*b*b-(c=a*a+b*b-c*c)*c)/4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFtT4MwEMff71NcMEsKKxsT9hScb4yfwi2mLWUSWUFKInHZVxePUVDmCiXH/f53vbsKV6RMHer6LpJxoiTEhFFOha0/ipIEDsOHO9wlYovmpDGFI2x8Z0GdqBKOLFHEhtMIcDWOUurylb3sYQunOQWfwuYcDinvaYCCayp6uqCwMjROM1aCrHIpShm1Cm8a@L5HYTn1cFFYT1frxdIEiEzpEsQbKxz8SvEuizbK2lXP97tq84R7YVH4@@9bw@NynaSZwqi5dANDsgJIU2uiIlkh8kJjPoBOvmQWk65Ke2YcTu8JYTK5qO1LsnZqXfcMs5npXTT7cIB5h/lNLDos/uG2G42C5naBUxD2NZVI@/Heyp8zfcnAuCYSXNA2dmwm9KvMC9TGxBpHFNoN7iOMYxjrncJpD/qjw37osH4KmvZX15y@N0WfR@f6W8QpO@ja/azd9PgD)

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to [jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt)!!!*

Answer (score 3):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$9\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 7.408 bytes

```
mqr-J0xHS
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJtcXItSjB4SFMiLCJbMyw0LDVdIl0=)

Jelly beats me... again. Takes input as a list of the side lengths.

```
mqr-J0xHS
        S # Sum the lengths
       H  # Halve it
   -      # That ^ minus...
      x   # The input
    J0    # With a 0 prepended
  r       # Product
mq        # Square root
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
∑½₌N-Π*√
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiJHCveKCjE4tzqAq4oiaIiwiIiwiOSwzLDciXQ==)

*[A 7 byter with `-r`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuItyIiwiIiwi4oiRwr1+Lc6gKuKImiIsIiIsIjksMyw3Il0=)*

Outputs as a fraction representation. [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCLiiJHCvSR+Lc6g4oCeKuKImiIsIiIsIjksMyw3Il0=) if you want decimals as output.

Takes the 3 side lengths as a list of numbers.

Quite literal implementation of Heron's formula, with some extra insight from Bubbler's answer.

### Explained

```
∑½₌N-Π*√
∑½       # Half sum of the side lengths
  ₌N-    # Push the half sum negated, as well as each side length minus the half sum
     Π*  # Take the product of the subtracted side lengths and multiply it by the negated half sum
       √ # Take the square root of that
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```factor
[ dup Σ 2 / dup rot n-v Π * √ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFXmpeZnJ@SCuZARMpSQWqLIZy00rzkksz8vGKFgqLUkpLKgqLMvBIFay6uagVDMKwFsowVTBRMwSxLINscyPofrZBSWqBwbrGCkYI@mFmUX6KQp1umcG6BgpbCo45ZCrH/S4oyHRT0ihWSc1ITi/4DAA)

-1 byte because I remembered `√` is 1 byte shorter than `sqrt`.

```
        ! { 3 4 5 }
dup     ! { 3 4 5 } { 3 4 5 }
Σ       ! { 3 4 5 } 12
2       ! { 3 4 5 } 12 2
/       ! { 3 4 5 } 6
dup     ! { 3 4 5 } 6 6
rot     ! 6 6 { 3 4 5 }
n-v     ! 6 { 3 2 1 }
Π       ! 6 6
*       ! 36
√       ! 6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 38 bytes

```
sqrt.product.(map=<<(-).(/2).sum).(0:)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ2W0km6Ec0CAUuzSNAVbhZilpSVpuhY31YoLi0r0CoryU0qTS_Q0chMLbG1sNHQ19TT0jTT1iktzgSwDK02oaqvcxMw8oG6gMt94BY2Cosy8EgU9hTRNhehoQx0FEIrVUYg21lEw0VEwBTEtdRSAPPPYWIgJCxZAaAA)

---

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 38 bytes

```
sqrt.product.(map.(-).(/2).sum<*>(0:))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ2W0km6Ec0CAUuzSNAVbhZilpSVpuhY31YoLi0r0CoryU0qTS_Q0chML9DR0NfU09I009YpLc2207DQMrDQ1oaqtchMz84C6gcp84xU0Cooy80oU9BTSNBWiow11FEAoVkch2lhHwURHwRTEtNRRAPLMY2MhJixYAKEB)

With the help of [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/).

Comment: I tried to write a SML answer, but it's very annoying as I don't know of ways of doing the 0 append pointfree, or doing sum and product without defining my own functions (i don't know of builtins that do it).

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
0Γ_Σ½-ε*√
```

I/O as decimals.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/g3OT4c4sP7dU9t1XrUces//8N9QwUoJjLGEibALEpkG0JpEF8cz0DAA)

**Explanation:**

Similar approach as [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250460/52210), except with subtract instead of absolute difference, since with four values the negatives balance themselves out anyway.

```python
0          # Push a 0
 Γ         # Wrap the top four items into a list (using the three implicit inputs)
  _        # Duplicate this list
   Σ       # Sum
    ½      # Halve
     -     # Subtract it from each value in the list
      ε*   # Product: reduce by multiplication
        √  # Square root
           # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 15 bytes

```
0+]J++2./?-pdr@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V9dUPzfQDvWS1vbSE/fXrcgpcjhf214zn9DPQMFKOYyBtImQGwKZFsCaRDfXM8AAA)

A port of [Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250460/91386)

```
0+] # Prepend 0
J   # Duplicate
++  # Sum
2./ # Halve
?-  # Difference with original
pd  # Product
r@  # Square root
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 36 bytes

```
f(l)=(total(ll)^2-2l^4.total)^{.5}/4
```

Input is a list of the three side lengths.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ttfj5rs9mm)

Port of [Steffan's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250449/96039) also gives 36 bytes:

```
f(a,b,c)=(4aabb-(aa+bb-cc)^2)^{.5}/4
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 14 bytes

```
√·×´+´∘÷⟜2-0⊸∾
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=QXJlYSDihpAg4oiawrfDl8K0K8K04oiYw7fin5wyLTDiirjiiL4KQXJlYcKoIOKfqDHigL8x4oC/MSwz4oC/NOKAvzUsOeKAvzPigL834p+p)

```
            0⊸∾     # each element of the argument, prepended by a zero
           -        # subtracted from
    +´∘             # the sum of
       ÷⟜2          # each element of the argument divided by 2
  ×´                # get the product (fold-multiply),
√·                  # and take the square root
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, 43 bytes (@Steffan)

Ported from [Steffan's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250449) by him:

```js
f=
(a,b,c)=>(4*a*a*b*b-(a*a+b*b-c*c)**2)**.5/4

console.log(f(1, 1, 1), 0.4330)
console.log(f(3, 4, 5), 6.0000)
console.log(f(9, 3, 7), 8.7856)
```

### JavaScript, 46 bytes (me)

Boring answer :/ but couldn't think of anything better.
\$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\textrm{, where } s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}\$.

```js
f=
(a,b,c,s=(a+b+c)/2)=>(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))**.5

console.log(f(1, 1, 1), 0.4330)
console.log(f(3, 4, 5), 6.0000)
console.log(f(9, 3, 7), 8.7856)
```

Comment: 43 bytes by porting my Python answer: `(a,b,c)=>(4*a*a*b*b-(a*a+b*b-c*c)**2)**.5/4`

Answer (score 1):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 33 bytes

```
6A 03 59 D9 E8 D9 EE DC E1 DA 04 8C E2 FB D9 FD 6A 03 59 D9 C0 DA 2C 8C DE CA E2 F7 DE C9 D9 FA C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJNj9MwED1nfsVQVMluXUjaRYiGctorAlVIIHV7SB27jeQ6wXaWsFX/OmWcbQvLClmayXy992YUOdlKeTq9rKw0banwvQ9lVb/afYCnKRtiDrSpi4CaUYyFwOg2j07yHO/rqkRlS8ZzKPwe2XLAQM@TpvU7nOXY1A0q2UGiTZn19oGsbzcOfWAZF9GlHEw6T3RVlCXefv20vMXPX5a4Ur4Z34xofA2JqQnJpHFYFkbBMwaTzSP8GY/AepL/oOl9a5rYOr0qODNkfxX/yCPW7y5A4lQA2nYOfEALy9r60J8iyNUaF3iATMQHM3Ej3gh4J2birYBUTOnBMQeIzfuiso/ndFspUO4Kh6MRBfccDpDESpdja321tao8111OImqHrCOeNMcOXyzQVw@q1ixIjq8vAY3zWB4vcEbCk8ZRRrPBUN/ZgcDYverWIkruxtnlY7rmtFAC1/Y7@7GQu8oqlHWp5nHdxBE1e6JrxDXlyxoPlzkcptNvxDNy4zHPj/hjVxmFzEW57J@dOJ0y4l5n2bDCzc@gPO@1Opw8n9G9EhVaZ@kOcITT6ZfUptj602Q/m5Kh/3BBgMr8Bg)

Uses the `cdecl` calling convention, taking three 32-bit integers on the stack and returning a value on the FPU register stack.

In assembly:

```
f:  push 3; pop ecx     # Set ECX to 3.
    fld1                # Push 1 onto the FPU register stack.
    fldz                # Push 0 onto the FPU register stack.
    fsubr st(1), st(0)  # Change the 1 to 0-1=-1.
l0: fiadd DWORD PTR [esp+4*ecx] # Add an argument to the top value.
    loop l0                     # Loop 3 times, making the top value a+b+c.
    fscale              # Multiply the top value by 2^(value below)=2^-1=1/2.
    push 3; pop ecx     # Set ECX to 3 again.
l1: fld st(0)                   # Duplicate the top value, which is s.
    fisubr DWORD PTR [esp+4*ecx]# Change the top value to a-s or b-s or c-s.
    fmulp st(2), st(0)          # Multiply the third-from-top value
                                # (which was -1) by that and pop it.
    loop l1                     # Loop 3 times.
                        # The FPU register stack is now -(a-s)(b-s)(c-s), s.
    fmulp st(1), st(0)  # Multiply those values and pop, leaving the product.
    fsqrt               # Take the square root.
    ret                 # Return.
```

---

I had another version using SIMD instructions to do multiple calculations at once, but it was longer, at 48 bytes:

```
5A 6A 00 89 E1 F8 C5 F8 5B 01 0F 59 C0 C5 FB 7C C8 C5 F3 7C C9 F3 0F 11 09 D9 01 F5 72 EC D8 C0 D9 C1 DE CA DE E9 D9 FA 58 6A 04 DA 31 58 FF E2
```

```
f:  pop edx
    push 0
    mov ecx, esp
    clc
    vcvtdq2ps xmm0, [ecx]
r:  mulps xmm0, xmm0
    vhaddps xmm1, xmm0, xmm0
    vhaddps xmm1, xmm1, xmm1
    movss [ecx], xmm1
    fld DWORD PTR [ecx]
    cmc
    jc r
    fadd st(0), st(0)
    fld st(1)
    fmulp st(2), st(0)
    fsubp
    fsqrt
    pop eax
    push 4
    fidiv DWORD PTR [ecx]
    pop eax
    jmp edx
```

Answer (score 1):

## Knight, 50 bytes

```
;=x=s-**4=a^P2=b^P2^+a-b^P2 2;W>x=x/+x/s x 2xO/x 4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVlbU9tKEn62f8XgFLZGloMsnK1TNjJFciBFLYEcSDYP4AQhy1i1suyVZC5L2L@e7e65aGSb7Gb38CBpZvr6TU93jwk7t2H441WchslyHO3lxTiev54O6@ZMEt9UpsLicRGtEGVxeluZKuKZoBlHkziNWJKwZJ7e0qOuZz@dfv7AuuXw4tM588rh3w7OWa8cHp2@Y7@Vw/PPrFsSH51cGLSnn08M0s@nHw4u/mrlnFn4aLJ/dd9wvXpwAWrFYjgNMmbzksGkAlu1iOGQ9cq108MvuJjCInn0neH33t4KDaohGnQTaJKEI2GF5u3Z2QkR4WOfnOyjb4Yh5@8FAfAbtt4FyTLi/DId8Xqd/IBduRz5543DsyPrx8B/8POObff84OtHz7@Bx9d20ME38wZfhg/@w077YSdnD8x7ONt5YL0fHBgbAyHLBmFRMGM@Sh3U66B6EWR5ZHH2VK/FacHiQb0Gs2SGw@zJMg1hhphDGBezhZMv0ktv5D@5jvsMMmoxiCN6eLs4sbOD4uMFu5/GRZQvgjCq1@A7iSyYB3ZLmOGwxlVxlV5NrjL29Hw5snj/VYOTKbV4wixtrc9ar1qcCRFqdgtmr1KYbrfFDNhZi5I8MieehTnhNAr/zibzjKXL2U2U5dIeZsX5OL6NCyUVtKM7XUd7JN4267qszWxpebvNWYe13BaoQEtjzrKoWGYpU4Ej2Ch2Bqs23AVZHNwkkbICjEjm91FmhaBPGcK@f2fKuJBGIQHxrcUlPPEG12O/68Ae@Xp6xTo8ijJkgSQdLxcWbimTmHYYjNYNFokhF9KEGVetVmlToyU2DZjBA20UAyGQSOAbLFsEecGKaQTCgqwAYrkBtkIUNzTk6Iky1jhfLxoLzy6nja6VYJD5GLpFPE/BbIxYdwSmhQqRfLlYIOBcRZWaMeE34w9gN8BGGSqUFynEMSQ1jFxpuUDlU0uffDFxhBOY4PqY2NBMFWSUE4WrFtqNpgZJMg@tnut0OTqI09oJcjBdJkmQPZqOlvtzbmzPx5a2jBRK/mW6wk0quqhCJoVNnh4cvn13/cfWye9nhsOm2Jt4o1xvXe5WRfD744sXJBZRRiKDdMz@sQzUEMXemSp211UIAN63NBbHG7Ag5l6VuUrzTKkyW6a4QwOZmO1inlsqV9IBgNAu4pDR6s1ycun1RtIOsdFNSg/agHwBx6qYWEAK/m8nybih8g4VJgeFrAqAQ6EFiJIn9Ffo9lh3t@onOo@xuM8aRbaMGhCDeh5DEuYnAWQQXGhgZDVKENBP9F3WJoLj29v5PIGVmyoCL/pauvUzh@xf98g082bNzARtTP9UGyFoi3mSWKapDnMdqBD/g8npmslYhT8cfDx1sBaLQIPh8WXXdV0IJ3AFhmqUx/@MvhUMXwMjRg1vEQEYOfjw6Lnrd1VJxwyHVR1f9PTEaxcIjo5PDm02geQ4qOnQlvowDYfBwkmilDoAAyvVOgnM4Ny9BMYqI9YmLG1YcKyYegmoxXuExQCKSoyLOm@Es8XKDhBI8ahMIQhTPEI1@X1chFPLBmTWOi3AiMm/EOtU66DVZ6hFEPgIKPZqkIV5k5yS4mW3WAlZPqAqXFJQS1pkWLqoK70c8acyzKCBotwuFJ@D4qrsDDKexZvuwwT/SsqPQAlSBUa3UZFAQ2k1aS@buENYIsdxygfxxLJoP7EhCKcZ2uJAnHIuttl3BxtthRenNkDoOxT6ROeI2UACMlD2Ikgyd5ZWvi39EfR65V25gpwmxJrmGmgwGiD@/MV8EaWWodhpZA1qFcAqfyYqJcSj77m932heNheW6EgmYPoYnYIWDkLWwf4OyKF3oBHqANUqvCyYZG2fWiE8sUDJJdwgh3QR1CjB9pln9iwljKUnf4An0QO0cXja1/zcquw63Ru2MJOtEZ6shQdoSaq4GOS/t/qyT9wQyDrzyQrUOKW22MIaxFURGg57vGws19KhYr2g5tDazpGxehjWmQFOaH1MvZBJeaMkVQtYXqIglWJfKmGyZpk7IHOLROGsRAEPhrj4IGhiPyvQsWaTLludDpKORJt7Re12TZm1/drOwR4LRpypo5YZ5i@LXO2@jgnR6wmD2togypOQLzElY2gZ2yO66Vp1t8XNFamh72cqljyx59j/0mEQG0BUOI2n3FdeenxzqIZBoV6y6@y2S5i4@kZZHLpRh96FzBHSr85adBrRjq161V7BZJe7swGF1fK8AQd7DQexr5tQmG1wzSYa3xRCDFCDLMqQfusKLnlINOh0SJ4Eikrm6kYLRIvK6d/5KTA7m4HZ/inT9mamr4RmxSFxdaA5z/RyIGEXqPus09UoEy1A34Vz1unCGeuaxN4vUu9BeqzQ@j6Skt6@mnEV5AS0N3Ql1h6ndsX2Cf/66oGgRXIF7giUYLHEwDdeGaZRFrVyls6hh46TIk7ZffAIuLHxHO6kRXQbZcCzmKdRWsQB3iLgJM/ZfcSmwV0EhFIQkhdsFqRLCJ/H1ziL3t0g4gAFIZEvkwJ/NCDlOuEpko5Jo1SuQGbyaZIV8SjvZUr3ZUM02V6FyqX7eZBgbXwEr9NxEo3ZdWn2tZbyhF@iMTOUlM4MUVino8acyGuS1DZMf9Z5cI@CdaXwYdKr5EW/mhX3mXn498xjgKx9@ZtckwmCfVZpFGnSYUY2RBmu4FQl1xN1AGm3fKg2Rhc0hEOJoTUfz/tsFs3CBYZZyobX@/@vK8M/wZWhcmVrgy@@9EW6sv8y@kLrBpNxeZ9VCDxN4akCurXJznKg3VOZxxSgzWuW6Q992VQb9k1OmUo0//f/hl/mIEOM5h@0@iZ1pc1dpfXLrFtd/uWLjOpty5sM0tUqtxmdCokGJY78CreRJpEDKdptzSZM/gLuiV@9zEaz4h0zexfJdlzt2pHU4N/3@rsGLO/FlcE3Oqy2WYDW70ipvHg4@izsVhraCwH0itDBasnzNpW8Xa77AE9z92jyPzREaBi@cStC3fzrdsjsjTzwELW2u9gkUYMg4l8s0oso2vIkgPZxNAkgSYJnqsOMU1iMx/QjUhAWUKZa22ELe06c4eyFWywK0zUQukH5Q8IsiFNsVlmQ3YYOCbVt@L7j@HMV3S/xXzyWS9ZUr3HPP97U39T/8m8)

This is the elusive "triple Heron" answer:

- Because of the limitations of Knight, this only works for Heronian triangles (triangles with integer sides and area)
- It uses Heron's formula for the area of the triangle
- Because Knight doesn't have square root, I implemented it using Heron's method.

<s>(It doesn't work in the TIO because it hasn't implemented the no-op.)</s> It turns out I just misread the spec.

Here's the expanded code:

```
;=a^P2
;=b^P2
;=c^P2
;=s (-(*(*4a) b)(^(+a(-b c)) 2))
;=x s
;WHILE >x (=x(/+x(/s x) 2)) 
  x
OUTPUT /x 4
```

Comment: For a no-op, you can just use `1` or something. It will work on TIO. Also, `:` is treated as whitespace, so it doesn't take up the whole while block.

Comment: @Steffan I can't use a number in this case because it would get parsed with the `2`. Is `:` actually completely equivalent to whitespace?

Comment: Yes, `:` is equivalent to whitespace. It's documented in the spec. You can also use one of `NTF`, but it will be grouped with `O`

Comment: The spec says that it "can (usually) be considered whitespace", not that it's always the same as whitespace.

Comment: Actually, you're right. But this code is still invalid. `:` takes an argument, and it will consume `O/x 4` for that argument. And it is implemented in TIO. In this code, it is equivalent to whitespace. It is only not equivalent at the end of a program.

Comment: I somehow didn't realize that `:` takes an argument, whoops. Edit: wait, I can just use a variable, duh

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 27 bytes

```
{sqrt [*] @_.sum/2 X-0,|@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/uriwqEQhWitWwSFer7g0V99IIULXQKfGIb72f3FipYKSSryCrZ1CdZqCSnytkkJafpGCjaECENrpKNgYK5gomIIYlgrGCuZ2/wE)

`@_` is the array of arguments to the function: *a*, *b*, and *c*.  `@_.sum / 2` is half the sum of the arguments, what the problem statement calls *s*.  `X-` subtracts the numbers `0` and `|@_`, the flattened arguments, from that number, producing the numbers *s*, *s - a*, *s - b*, and *s - c*.  Then `[*]` multiplies them together and `sqrt` takes the square root.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 14 bytes

```
√(sum(Ans)/2prod(sum(Ans)/2-Ans
```

or

```
.25√(sum(Ans)prod(sum(Ans)-2Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans` as a list.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 43 bytes

Tried to beat `43` bytes but got a different form :)

$$
\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}
$$

where \$s=\frac{a + b + c}{2}\$ is equal to:

$$
\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{4abd - d^2}
$$

where \$d=(a + b)^2 - c^2\$

```
(a,b,c)=>(4*a*b*(d=(a+b)**2-c*c)-d*d)**.5/4
```

Try it:

```js
f=(a,b,c)=>(4*a*b*(d=(a+b)**2-c*c)-d*d)**.5/4

;[
  [1, 1, 1], // 0.4330
  [3, 4, 5], // 6.0000
  [9, 3, 7], // 8.7856
].forEach(([a,b,c])=>console.log(f(a,b,c)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [lin](https://github.com/molarmanful/lin), 25 bytes

```
.+ \+ `/2/.~0' - \* `/.5^
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-lin)

For testing purposes (use `-i` flag if running locally):

```
[1 1 1] ;
.+ \+ `/2/.~0' - \* `/.5^
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
.+ \+ `/ 2/.~ 0' - \* `/ .5^
```

- `` .+ \+ `/ 2/ `` duplicate, half-sum of input
- `.~ 0'` swap, append 0
- `` - \* `/ .5^ `` vector subtract, product, square root

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
Ｉ₂Π⁻⊘Σθ⊞Ｏθ⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcHBCsIwDADQX@kxhQqCBxGPXrwMy3ocO4SusEG32DTZ70fwvbwiZ8JqFnk7BF7YBVJT5DISCUSmRbPAsB3a4Y31LAsk3aF5H1zUvn6@hVGIoQV39X9Ps2l6BHcL7j7PdjnrDw) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as an array. Explanation:

```
      θ     Input array
     Σ      Summed
    ⊘       Halved
   ⁻        Vectorised subtract
          ⁰ Literal integer `0`
       ⊞Ｏ   Appended to
         θ  Input array
  Π         Take the product
 ₂          Take the square root
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```ruby
->a,b,c{(4*a*a*b*b-(a*a+b*b-c*c)**2)**0.5/4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ0knuVrDRCsRCJO0knQ1gAxtECNZK1lTS8sIiA30TPVNav8XKKRFG@oAYSwXiGmsY6JjCmFa6hjrmMf@BwA)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.inject(s=a.sum/2.0){|p,i|p*(s-i)}**0.5}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOlEvMy8rNblEo9g2Ua@4NFffSM9As7qmQCezpkBLo1g3U7NWS8tAz7T2f4FCWnS0oQ4QxsZygTnGOiY6pjCOpY6xjnls7H8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=product,sum -pal`, 37 bytes

```perl
$_=sqrt product map{sum(@F)/2-$_}0,@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4sKhEoaAoP6U0uUQhN7Ggurg0V8PBTVPfSFclvtZAx8Ht/39DBSDkMlYwUTDlslQwVjD/l19QkpmfV/xf19dUz8DQAEj7ZBaXWFmFlmTm2EJN0wGa9F@3IDEHAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
@*F-LcsQ2+QZ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/30HLTdcnuTjQSDswyuj//2hDHQUQigUA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 52 bytes

```cs
(a,b,c)=>Math.Sqrt((a-(a=(a+b+c)/2))*(b-a)*(c-a)*-a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxCsJAEERr8xVb7pqNolFEYlLaCYKlWOytCQnIBS8XLcRvPxNIKcO8mWZGu0S7Jhx7q4d725tHyfA/C6ggDyhsWCkvTuLrxeXpPKIkKDlKbGKl5ZpojiaRgTpycMiiqnWlaI0vcTBdQGPBlu/r7YMrHkQMmPKGt2PZc8o7@lI0O7vGeqymEWXhBw)

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##bYuxCsIwFEVn@xVvfKmvijQiUtPRTRAcxSF5NrQgKaapDuK3xxQ6yrlwz3J4KHjo4nF0fLj3o3k0BP@/BgsqoiZDLFR90qFdXZ4@oMx1wuSmQFZJl5NyziJtLWOV2d43mlt8aQ9zD50D17yvtw9uKCEIsCRJ20n2VNJOfEW2OPvOBbRzJKr4Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 38 bytes

```arturo
$[a][d://∑a 2sqrt d*∏map a=>[d-&]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?fr6sKV)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 10 bytes

```
ĐƩᵮ₂Đ↔-Π*√
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIRjKx9uXfeoqenIhEdtU3TPLdB61DHr//9oQx0gjAUA)

Straightforward implementation of Heron's formula

```
Đ                 implicit input; Đuplicate
 Ʃ                Ʃum
  ᵮ₂              cast to ᵮloat; halve
    Đ             Đuplicate
     ↔            flip stack
      -           subtract
       Π          take product of list
        *         multiply by s
         √        square root; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 10 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 8.23 bytes

```
0ZNDS2/_Pt
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuharDKL8XIKN9OMDSiACUPEFK6ONdRRMdBRMYyECAA)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
0ZNDS2/_Pt  # Implicit input
0ZN         # Prepend a 0
   DS       # Duplicate and sum
     2/     # Halve
       _    # Subtract the list
        P   # Product
         t  # Square root
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 18 bytes

```
RT$*Y($+YgPE0)/2-y
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhabgkJUtCI1VLQj0wNcDTT1jXQrIRJQ-ZXRxjoKJjoKprFQAQA)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
RT$*Y($+YgPE0)/2-y  # Input on command line
         gPE0       # Prepend 0 to the input
      $+Y           # Sum and store in y
     (       )/2    # Halve
                -y  # And subtract y
  $*Y               # Get the product
RT                  # And square root
                    # Implicit output
```